# IL2CPP Build error for android (Unity 2022.2.1f1)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build, arm64, il2cpp

I had to change Mono to IL2CPP so that I can use the ARM64 to publish my game on Google Play. But every time I build I get those errors.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

This is what the error looks like:

```
 Building Library\Bee\artifacts\Android\d8kzr\libil2cpp.so failed with output:
 ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: GADUCreateRequest
 >>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19545 (C:/Users/yasse/Downloads/OR-Bit Final/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19545)
 >>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/kfoj_ly-CSharp1.o:(Externs_GADUCreateRequest_m92CFE3D243AF8E0DD001F210BF3ED17E1F21DA5D)
 >>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19545 (C:/Users/yasse/Downloads/OR-Bit Final/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19545)
 >>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/kfoj_ly-CSharp1.o:(IOSBannerClient_LoadAd_mD95ECC13BAE7744AB2A65F46D8F564DAB326BF7A)
 >>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19545 (C:/Users/yasse/Downloads/OR-Bit Final/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19545)
 >>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/kfoj_ly-CSharp1.o:(IOSInterstitialClient_LoadAd_mBD86127148FE6D83340E947592B1ADF3982BFED2)
 
 ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: GADUAddTestDevice
 >>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19556 (C:/Users/yasse/Downloads/OR-Bit Final/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19556)
 >>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/kfoj_ly-CSharp1.o:(Externs_GADUAddTestDevice_m17589AA3E8171DC377C31D89A023A4FDFCA0891E)
 >>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19556 (C:/Users/yasse/Downloads/OR-Bit Final/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19556)
 >>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/kfoj_ly-CSharp1.o:(IOSBannerClient_LoadAd_mD95ECC13BAE7744AB2A65F46D8F564DAB326BF7A)
 >>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19556 (C:/Users/yasse/Downloads/OR-Bit Final/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19556)
 >>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/kfoj_ly-CSharp1.o:(IOSInterstitialClient_LoadAd_mBD86127148FE6D83340E947592B1ADF3982BFED2)
 
 ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: GADUAddKeyword
 >>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19569 (C:/Users/yasse/Downloads/OR-Bit Final/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19569)
 >>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/kfoj_ly-CSharp1.o:(Externs_GADUAddKeyword_m844145F383BE68AE2AB6D35EF45F719F4588A388)
 >>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19569 (C:/Users/yasse/Downloads/OR-Bit Final/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19569)
 >>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/kfoj_ly-CSharp1.o:(IOSBannerClient_LoadAd_mD95ECC13BAE7744AB2A65F46D8F564DAB326BF7A)
 >>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19569 (C:/Users/yasse/Downloads/OR-Bit Final/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19569)
 >>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/kfoj_ly-CSharp1.o:(IOSInterstitialClient_LoadAd_mBD86127148FE6D83340E947592B1ADF3982BFED2)
 
 ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: GADUSetBirthday
 >>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19579 (C:/Users/yasse/Downloads/OR-Bit Final/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19579)
 >>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/kfoj_ly-CSharp1.o:(Externs_GADUSetBirthday_m4FEA770DF974EC8065D1DE3FCF11D5FEA2BFAD07)
 >>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19579 (C:/Users/yasse/Downloads/OR-Bit Final/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19579)
 >>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/kfoj_ly-CSharp1.o:(IOSBannerClient_LoadAd_mD95ECC13BAE7744AB2A65F46D8F564DAB326BF7A)
 >>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19579 (C:/Users/yasse/Downloads/OR-Bit Final/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19579)
 >>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/kfoj_ly-CSharp1.o:(IOSInterstitialClient_LoadAd_mBD86127148FE6D83340E947592B1ADF3982BFED2)
 
 ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: GADUSetGender
 >>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19586 (C:/Users/yasse/Downloads/OR-Bit Final/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19586)
 >>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/kfoj_ly-CSharp1.o:(Externs_GADUSetGender_m69B0124644BA18A1076920321A3F6C7D01721F3F)
 >>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19586 (C:/Users/yasse/Downloads/OR-Bit Final/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19586)
 >>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/kfoj_ly-CSharp1.o:(IOSBannerClient_LoadAd_mD95ECC13BAE7744AB2A65F46D8F564DAB326BF7A)
 >>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19586 (C:/Users/yasse/Downloads/OR-Bit Final/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19586)
 >>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/kfoj_ly-CSharp1.o:(IOSInterstitialClient_LoadAd_mBD86127148FE6D83340E947592B1ADF3982BFED2)
 
 ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: GADUTagForChildDirectedTreatment
 >>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19593 (C:/Users/yasse/Downloads/OR-Bit Final/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19593)
 >>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/kfoj_ly-CSharp1.o:(Externs_GADUTagForChildDirectedTreatment_m5758B356E40BAD3B13E126B140F356ECB647C125)
 >>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19593 (C:/Users/yasse/Downloads/OR-Bit Final/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19593)
 >>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/kfoj_ly-CSharp1.o:(IOSBannerClient_LoadAd_mD95ECC13BAE7744AB2A65F46D8F564DAB326BF7A)
 >>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19593 (C:/Users/yasse/Downloads/OR-Bit Final/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19593)
 >>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/kfoj_ly-CSharp1.o:(IOSInterstitialClient_LoadAd_mBD86127148FE6D83340E947592B1ADF3982BFED2)
 
 ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: GADUSetExtra
 >>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19606 (C:/Users/yasse/Downloads/OR-Bit Final/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19606)
 >>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/kfoj_ly-CSharp1.o:(Externs_GADUSetExtra_m3C579DA3641DA1528B598BBC03158624A6A5C881)
 
 ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: GADURelease
 >>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19619 (C:/Users/yasse/Downloads/OR-Bit Final/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19619)
 >>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/kfoj_ly-CSharp1.o:(Externs_GADURelease_mCE322D1A00BD98DAFCFE4636F91F5B57FFF4D3CF)
 >>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19619 (C:/Users/yasse/Downloads/OR-Bit Final/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19619)
 >>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/kfoj_ly-CSharp1.o:(IOSBannerClient_set_BannerViewPtr_m84E3666CAF9068D98BA8488C4CE4AE19FF910409)
 >>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:0 (C:/Users/yasse/Downloads/OR-Bit Final/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:0)
 >>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/kfoj_ly-CSharp1.o:(IOSBannerClient_CreateBannerView_m5FDC0388D0038FB907D5F187873C3E5BEA9E7798)
 >>> referenced 6 more times
 
 ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: GADUCreateBannerView
 >>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19629 (C:/Users/yasse/Downloads/OR-Bit Final/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19629)
 >>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/kfoj_ly-CSharp1.o:(Externs_GADUCreateBannerView_m56A97F911433B1BA948AEF83003AE54ECCEE6242)
 >>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19629 (C:/Users/yasse/Downloads/OR-Bit Final/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19629)
 >>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/kfoj_ly-CSharp1.o:(IOSBannerClient_CreateBannerView_m5FDC0388D0038FB907D5F187873C3E5BEA9E7798)
 
 ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: GADUCreateSmartBannerView
 >>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19643 (C:/Users/yasse/Downloads/OR-Bit Final/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19643)
 >>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/kfoj_ly-CSharp1.o:(Externs_GADUCreateSmartBannerView_m9DF02D8A7A1036C78360F208FA114E56336BFFF2)
 >>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19643 (C:/Users/yasse/Downloads/OR-Bit Final/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19643)
 >>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/kfoj_ly-CSharp1.o:(IOSBannerClient_CreateBannerView_m5FDC0388D0038FB907D5F187873C3E5BEA9E7798)
 
 ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: GADUSetBannerCallbacks
 >>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19672 (C:/Users/yasse/Downloads/OR-Bit Final/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19672)
 >>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/kfoj_ly-CSharp1.o:(Externs_GADUSetBannerCallbacks_mAE442270D8FD4BC56629377781F6D650C5E49298)
 
 ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: GADUHideBannerView
 >>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19679 (C:/Users/yasse/Downloads/OR-Bit Final/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19679)
 >>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/kfoj_ly-CSharp1.o:(Externs_GADUHideBannerView_m324D7258942EC48519BF0A79C39792DC5F57B0D8)
 >>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19679 (C:/Users/yasse/Downloads/OR-Bit Final/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19679)
 >>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/kfoj_ly-CSharp1.o:(IOSBannerClient_HideBannerView_m77CBE597E0E1DBEA709A713F067A3AC60257D466)
 
 ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: GADUShowBannerView
 >>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19686 (C:/Users/yasse/Downloads/OR-Bit Final/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19686)
 >>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/kfoj_ly-CSharp1.o:(Externs_GADUShowBannerView_m3AE326325B91E0CA79F0136571780E74B7F6102E)
 >>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19686 (C:/Users/yasse/Downloads/OR-Bit Final/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19686)
 >>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/kfoj_ly-CSharp1.o:(IOSBannerClient_ShowBannerView_mF5DA6D32F68F3049450B7675461269735367BC60)
 
 ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: GADURemoveBannerView
 >>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19693 (C:/Users/yasse/Downloads/OR-Bit Final/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19693)
 >>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/kfoj_ly-CSharp1.o:(Externs_GADURemoveBannerView_mB860B3B0217E33F91B806E2BADFB1D92B3640FA0)
 >>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19693 (C:/Users/yasse/Downloads/OR-Bit Final/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19693)
 >>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/kfoj_ly-CSharp1.o:(IOSBannerClient_DestroyBannerView_mD904D590AF6C3F5E39303D71B3591C29D9FC0D54)
 
 ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: GADURequestBannerAd
 >>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19700 (C:/Users/yasse/Downloads/OR-Bit Final/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19700)
 >>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/kfoj_ly-CSharp1.o:(Externs_GADURequestBannerAd_m98461F3BE18282300662EA0111F21461673E6D4D)
 >>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19700 (C:/Users/yasse/Downloads/OR-Bit Final/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19700)
 >>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/kfoj_ly-CSharp1.o:(IOSBannerClient_LoadAd_mD95ECC13BAE7744AB2A65F46D8F564DAB326BF7A)
 
 ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: GADUCreateInterstitial
 >>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19710 (C:/Users/yasse/Downloads/OR-Bit Final/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19710)
 >>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/kfoj_ly-CSharp1.o:(Externs_GADUCreateInterstitial_m4A49389B3E932CAF5CEEA805C867C5FC2D24F1CC)
 >>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19710 (C:/Users/yasse/Downloads/OR-Bit Final/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19710)
 >>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/kfoj_ly-CSharp1.o:(IOSInterstitialClient_CreateInterstitialAd_m4F1992354616F0D071DE831DA0BEA2733531CF72)
 
 ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: GADUSetInterstitialCallbacks
 >>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19739 (C:/Users/yasse/Downloads/OR-Bit Final/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19739)
 >>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/kfoj_ly-CSharp1.o:(Externs_GADUSetInterstitialCallbacks_m968B4B5509527040D57AB1B32B17A468FBF8E47C)
 
 ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: GADUInterstitialReady
 >>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19746 (C:/Users/yasse/Downloads/OR-Bit Final/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19746)
 >>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/kfoj_ly-CSharp1.o:(Externs_GADUInterstitialReady_m99D605C6C0295F638CD4D1AF7E4C9AB10CADEAE8)
 >>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19746 (C:/Users/yasse/Downloads/OR-Bit Final/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19746)
 >>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/kfoj_ly-CSharp1.o:(IOSInterstitialClient_IsLoaded_m5FC29DCF18ECE98BB1915484A4D526862D211CC8)
 
 ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: GADUShowInterstitial
 >>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19754 (C:/Users/yasse/Downloads/OR-Bit Final/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19754)
 >>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/kfoj_ly-CSharp1.o:(Externs_GADUShowInterstitial_mE26F7E7C9EB61A92BFE32A49706D30DB15F71EF9)
 >>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19754 (C:/Users/yasse/Downloads/OR-Bit Final/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19754)
 >>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/kfoj_ly-CSharp1.o:(IOSInterstitialClient_ShowInterstitial_mA075D998A49F08504647F32D2E4F8E9944C0B1AE)
 
 ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: GADURequestInterstitial
 >>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19761 (C:/Users/yasse/Downloads/OR-Bit Final/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19761)
 >>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/kfoj_ly-CSharp1.o:(Externs_GADURequestInterstitial_m353F2481C9E3D9CAE99DBA615C24EA8468AEED6C)
 >>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19761 (C:/Users/yasse/Downloads/OR-Bit Final/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:19761)
 >>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/d8kzr/kfoj_ly-CSharp1.o:(IOSInterstitialClient_LoadAd_mBD86127148FE6D83340E947592B1ADF3982BFED2)
 clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
 
 UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

I tried with .NET Standard 2.1 and didn't work. Tried with Faster Runtime and still didn't work. Even with the Master Compiler configuration. I was expecting to receive a successful build notice.

Comment: How did you solve it. I am facing similar issue. Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Assembly-CSharp.cpp:7308: error: undefined reference to 'getAndroidId'